# Running selenium tests on a dockerized Wordpress Selenium PHP-composer setup

Tags: php, wordpress, docker, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm having trouble running tests on a Wordpress + Selenium + PHP Composer docker setup.

Basically, when the tests I made tries to access `http://<wordpress-container-id>/wp-admin/plugins.php` it redirects back to `http://localhost/wp-login.php`(since I'm not yet logged in). The problem there is that the `Selenium` container won't be able to find the Wordpress login page through `http://localhost/wp-login.php` because Wordpress is installed in a different container.

I was wondering if there's something wrong with my setup or if there's a way to not have the redirect change back to `localhost` or if I'm doing something wrong with my test.

Here's my setup.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  db: # wordpress db
    container_name: db
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
    networks:
      - test

  wordpress: # wordpress site
    container_name: wordpress
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    ports:
      - 80:80
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
    networks:
      - test

  selenium: # selenium server
    container_name: selenium
    image: selenium/standalone-chrome:latest
    ports:
      - 4444:4444
    networks:
      - test

  app: # my app which contains the test files
    container_name: app
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ../:/app
    networks:
      - test

volumes:
    db_data: {}

networks:
  test:
```

MyTest.php

```
<?php

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

use Facebook\WebDriver\Chrome\ChromeOptions;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver;
use Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverBy;

class Tests extends TestCase
{
    protected $driver;

    public function setup(): void
    {
        $options = new ChromeOptions();
        $options->addArguments(array('--headless'));

        $capabilities = DesiredCapabilities::chrome();
        $capabilities->setCapability(ChromeOptions::CAPABILITY_W3C, $options);

        $this->driver = RemoteWebDriver::create('selenium:4444', $capabilities);
    }

    public function tearDown(): void
    {
        $this->driver->quit();
    }

    public function test_login() {
        $this->driver->get('http://wordpress/wp-login.php');

        echo '\n';
        echo $this->driver->getCurrentURL(); // returns http://wordpress/wp-login.php

        $username = $this->driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::id('user_login'));
        $username->sendKeys('admin');

        $password = $this->driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::id('user_pass'));
        $password->sendKeys('admin');
        echo $password->getAttribute('value');

        $this->driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::id('wp-submit'))->click();

        echo '\n';
        echo $this->driver->getCurrentURL(); // returns http://localhost/wp-login.php

        $this->driver->get('wordpress:80/wp-admin/plugins.php');

        echo '\n';
        echo $this->driver->getCurrentURL(); // returns http://localhost/wp-login.php

        $this->driver->get('http://wordpress/wp-admin/plugins.php');

        echo '\n';
        echo $this->driver->getCurrentURL(); // throws net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
    }
}
```

The reason I'm trying to do this setup is that I'm trying to replicate the workflow that would happen in github actions when I'm going to run the selenium tests there. Since github actions uses docker containers to run Wordpress, the Selenium web drivers, and composer.

Edit:

After some digging around, I was able to resolve the issue by adding t his container to auto install Wordpress with the container name instead of `localhost`.

```
wordpress-cli:
    depends_on:
      - db
      - wordpress
    image: wordpress:cli
    command: >
      /bin/sh -c '
      sleep 10;
      wp core install --path="/var/www/html" --url=wordpress --title="Local Wordpress By Docker" --admin_user=admin --admin_password=admin --admin_email=foo@bar.com
      '
    networks:
      - test
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX: "wp_"
      WORDPRESS_DEBUG: 1
    volumes:
      - wp_data:/var/www/html
```